# Помогите разобраться с div'ами!

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

[image]

Котятки, прошу, не пиннайте сильно, помогите сверстать это чудо дивами. Таблицами бы давно сделал через rowspan=3, но говорят сейчас так не правильно :( div'овская конструкция должна быть железной (как  ;)

И вопрос: некоторые дивы должны как бы оставаться пустыми (в них jquery меняет bg-position) так вот, чтобы показывалось нужно ставит:   или прозрачную png(gif) 1x1 или будет достаточно ? Расскажите кто как делает (ie6,ie7 как бы желательно)?

Если что вот css, с чего я начал:

```
.slider {
width: 980px;
height: 260px;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #eee;
}

.mslide {
width: 710px;
height: 240px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #aaa;
}

.but1 {
width: 250px;
height: 80px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #555;
}

.but2 {
width: 250px;
height: 80px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #666;
}

.but3 {
width: 250px;
height: 80px;
padding: 0px;
background-color: #777;
}
```

Вот как работает сейчас, но всё равно откуда то лишние 10пх паддинга внизу и справа:

```
<div class="slider">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <td class="mslide" rowspan="3">m</td>
    <td class="but1">1</td><tr>
    <td class="but2">2</td><tr>    
    <td class="but3">3</td>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Не надо постить сюда простыни кода — есть http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: эммм...котятки?

Comment: @artuska НАДО постить код сюда, jsfiddle чтобы показать повторяемость ошибки, это сторонний сервис и если с него код исчезнет, вопрос станет бесполезным для сообщества. кроме того гугл может не найти вопрос без кода.

Comment: @eicto, нет не надо постить сюда простыни кода, я же выше написал это уже, зачем спорить? И с jsfiddle никуда код не денется — он там вечно стоит. А Гугл уж точно не будет разбираться, есть ли в вопросе код или нету, откуда такой бред взяли?

Comment: DreamChild, чем вас пугает такое обращение?

Comment: хотя бы тем, что я не знаю ни одной социальной группы, в которой это обращение было бы нормальным

Comment: Например я так обращаюсь к детям и близким мне по духу людям, больше девушкам конечно, но не думаю что в интернете это настолько важно. или звучит как то по обидному?

Comment: @eicto, нет не надо постить сюда простыни кода, я же выше написал это уже, зачем спорить? И с jsfiddle никуда код не денется — он там вечно стоит. А Гугл уж точно не будет разбираться, есть ли в вопросе код или нету, откуда такой бред взяли?

Comment: уж не сочтите за наглость, пожалуйста, но ни к девушкам, ни к детям большинство обитателей этого форума не относится, а фамильярность по отношению к незнакомым людям - ну это как-то не совсем хорошо, поэтому для меня это прозвучало несколько странно

Comment: @DreamChild я бы на вашем месте просто улыбнулся не считаю что "развязанный" стиль общения, хотя у каждого своё мнение, ну а то что странно немного -- возможно, но скажите, что в нашей жизни "немного" не СТРАННО?

Comment: @artuska 

 * про гугль: вот если я ищу по частям кода ?  
 * jsfiddle не вечен. (и иногда лежит кстати)
 * спорить, чтобы предотвратить вредную, с моей точки зрения, привычку у сообщества.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блоками **.but1—3** задайте *float:right;* и поместите их перед блоком **.mslide**. Ну и просто поиграйтесь с блоками, там же элементарно.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RPMrZ/

не получается пробовал миллион вариантов и откуда то ещё лишний паддинг внизу хотя расчитано всё по пикселям.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RPMrZ/3/ — ну просто поиграться с флоатами и попереставлять блоки

Comment: спасибо, а что насчет пустых дивов?

Comment: Ну, вы не можете попробовать стереть текст в диве и посмотреть, что будет? Ничего с ними не станет, просто оставляйте пустыми.

Comment: Я могу, но ещё хотелось бы знать как это будет как минимум, в ie6, ipad,  iphone, android'овский стандартный браузер и опера мобайл под андройд. а так спасибо!

Comment: Просто пустой блок без ничего. Это работает во всех браузерах.